# How do I give a default string value to a null cell in BIRT?

Tags: javascript, string, replace, birt

I am new to BIRT and javascript. I have made a report in which the null values are represented by blanks. I want to replace these blanks with a default string, for eg with "--".
This is how my current report is being displayed:

```
 Date         Temperature    Pressure    Weight    Colour
20130717       102                                  red
20130716                                   100      blue
20130715                        20         150
```

The blank spaces correspond to the null values of the columns in the database. Now, I want
the report to be displayed in the following manner:

```
 Date         Temperature    Pressure    Weight    Colour
20130717         102             --         --      red
20130716         --              --        100      blue
20130715         --              20        150       --
```

i.e., the cells with null values be replaced with a default string "--".
How do I do this in BIRT by using javascript or any other method? 
**Also, all the datasets are of the type varchar.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say what your data source is, but if it is SQL data base, use one of these SQL functions to convert the Null, in your SQL query.

```
ISNULL() 
NVL(),
IFNULL(),  
COALESCE()
```

Comment: Yes, it is an SQL datasource.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to do this would be to use `COALESCE` in the query for your dataset - like so:

```
SELECT ...
       COALESCE(Temperature, '--') as Temperature
       ...
```

However, if you want to do it in BIRT itself, one approach would be:

- Add a label item with `--` inside to each of your detail row cells;
- In the Property Editor, set the visibility of each of your data items to be hidden on a condition like: `row["temperature"]<=''` (using the appropriate column name).
- In the Property Editor, set the visibility of each of your `--` label items to be hidden on a condition like: `row["temperature"]>''` (using the appropriate column name).